# Rails, Model Association, Child belongs to parent and has_one parent relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails project, I'd like to have this structure:

> An argumentation has many arguments.
>
> An argument belongs to argumentation.
>
> An argument can have one argumentation (another one, a new one)

My models may look like this:

```
class Argument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :argumentation
  has_one :argumentation
end

class Argumentation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :argument
  has_many :arguments
end
```

Here an example, how I wish it should work:

> The argumentation called "Kant" has three arguments "a", "b" and "c".
>
> the argument "c" has an argumentation called "Metaphysics".
>
> the argumentation called "Metaphysics" has two arguments "d" and "e".
>
> And so on.

These are my questions:

1. Is this association even possible and recommendable?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this association even possible and recommendable?

Yes, it is possible.  You just have to set it up correctly.

First, make sure that you use 2 different association names.

```
class Argument < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :argumentation
  belongs_to :parent_argumentation, class_name: 'Argumentation'
end
```

Next, given the above associations, Rails expects a `parent_argumentation_id` column in the arguments table so add that.

Last is to declare the associations in the argumentation model

```
class Argumentation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :argument
  has_many :arguments, foreign_key: :parent_argumentation_id
end
```

Since you also have a `belongs_to` association declared here, you need to have an `argument_id` column in your argumentations table.

TIP: Use `inverse_of`

To make it easier to read and making it more efficient, set up the `inverse_of` option.

```
class Argument < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :argumentation, inverse_of: :argument
  belongs_to :parent_argumentation, class_name: 'Argumentation', inverse_of: :arguments
end

class Argumentation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :argument, inverse_of: :argumentation
  has_many :arguments, foreign_key: :parent_argumentation_id, inverse_of: :parent_argumentation
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `has_one :argumentation` as it is already a one to many relationship. So your models should look like this.

```
class Argument < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :argumentation
end

class Argumentation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :arguments
end
```

It means every argument will have one argumentaion only. This is how one to many relationship works. Ever argument will have only one `argumention_id` to which it belongs.

Comment: I'm not sure, if you see, what I am going for: Every argument can have an argumentation (another one, not the same as the parent).

Comment: I'm sorry i misunderstood your question.